# How to get string from textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

```
string text = Convert.ToString((bsoItemTrans.Transaction.TotalAmount * 100).ToString("000000000"));
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\movedir\SUBTOTALE.txt", text);
string sourcePath = @"C:\movedir\SUBTOTALE.txt";
string targetPath = @"C:\Cashmatic\SUBTOTALE.txt";
System.IO.File.Move(sourcePath, targetPath);
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("subtotale");
```

But where says "bsoItemTrans.Transaction.TotalAmount" want it to be the textbox text , I would like to know how I can do this.

Comment: `Int32.Parse(textbox.Text)` ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is kind of basic WinForms. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19tt6sk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RickAstley I tryed it and dont works

Comment: What do you mean by "don't works" - does it cause an exception or does it give an unexpected result.

Comment: @PaulF It says the operator "*" can be applied to "string" and "int". But what I want is to get the value instead of this " bsoItemTrans.Transaction.TotalAmount".

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: @PaulF the code I trying is on the main question, I just changed with what you suggested.

Comment: I haven't suggested anything - can you show exactly how you changed your code.

Comment: @PaulF string text = Int64.Parse((carregamento.Text * 100).ToString("000000000"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot multiply the string by 100, you need to convert to an integer first.

Try something like this :

```
Int64 ValFromTextBox;
if (! Int64.TryParse(carregamento.Text, out ValFromTextBox))
{
   // TELL USER NOT A NUMBER OR SOMETHING
}
string text = (ValFromTextBox * 100).ToString("000000000");
```